# Why is $\mu(E)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > **(Ergoden theorem)** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu,T)$ be an ergodic dynamical system and $f\in L_{\mu}^1$. Then
> >     $$
> > \lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k=\int f\, d\mu~~\text{a.s.}
> > $$

Proof.

Set $S_nf=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k$. Define $E:=\left\{\limsup_n\frac{1}{n}S_n f > \varepsilon\right\}$. Now it is shown that $E=\left\{\sup_n S_ng> 0\right\}$ for $g=(f-\varepsilon)1_E$.

With Hopf and Lebesgue it is shown that
$$
\mu(E)\leq\int_E f\, d\mu / \varepsilon.~~~(*)
$$

Now the argumentation is:

$E$ is $T$-invariant and the system is ergodic, so it follows $\mu(E)=0$.

I cannot see why in the end it follows from (*) that $\mu(E)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that somewhere during the proof (probably at the very beginning) one assumed without loss of generality that $\displaystyle\int_\Omega f\,\mathrm d\mu=0$.

The invariance of $E$ by $T$ and the ergodicity of $T$ imply that $\mu(E)=0$ or $\mu(E)=1$. If $\mu(E)=1$, then $\displaystyle\int_E f\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_\Omega f\,\mathrm d\mu=0$ hence $(\ast)$ implies that $\mu(E)\leqslant0$, which is absurd. Thus $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: Could you pls explain me, why from $\mu(E)=1$ it follows $\int_E f\, d\mu=\int_{\Omega} f\, d\mu =0$?

Comment: From $\mu(E) = 1$ it follows that $\int_E f\,d\mu = \int_{\Omega} f\,d\mu$, because $\Omega\setminus E$ is a null set. Why that is zero - as @Did wrote, this should be assumed at the beginning, without loss of generality.